# Firefox 407 proxy authentication

Tags: firefox, proxy, firefox-developer-tools

I go through a proxy at work.  I can access sites, however in the process firefox is reporting numerous 407 errors.  I receive the following pattern for numerous resources per request, but not ALL resources per request:

407 Proxy Authentication Required ( The ISA Server requires authentication to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy Filter is denied. )

407 Proxy Authentication Required ( Access is denied. )

200 Connection is established

So I might see this pattern for index.html or for main.css.  I'm not sure if firefox is not automatically providing proxy authentication as a part of each subrequest, or if this is a misconfigured proxy, or something else.

Here is a screenshot: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4l9nqfJR8eWdHdKQzdRTDNPOG8&authuser=0

Comment: Have you tried clearing your Browsers cache?

Comment: @New-To-IT Yes, clearing the cache does not change the results.

Comment: It's a bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=366562

Comment: @jgauffin - That bug appears to be associated with the proxy authentication dialog repeatedly popping up.  However, that is not my issue.  I have filed a bug - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1149523